# Ansible Playbook not resolving variable correctly

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible and having issues with running the playbook

site.yml:

```
---
- name: Test Ansible Playbook
  hosts: '{{ myhosts }}'
  sudo: no

  roles:
    - myRole
```

And the myRole file:

```
---
- name: Node script
  hosts: '{{ myhosts }}'
  sudo: no

  tasks:
   - name: Start Tomcat
     service: name=tomcat state=started enabled=yes
```

And when I try running the command: `ansible-playbook "-e 'myhosts=myHostName'" site.yml`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: hosts is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR: hosts is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

And that is the problem. Inside a tasks file of a role you may define tasks - nothing else. Which hosts these tasks will be executed on is defined in the playbook.

Your tasks file should only contain this:

```
---

- name: Start Tomcat
  service: name=tomcat
           state=started
           enabled=yes

...
```